# Android MediaRecorder getMaxAmplitude always returns 0 on Pixel XL

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

Below given code is working fine in other devices like Samsung and Honor but not working in Google Pixel XL. In pixel device recorder.getMaxAmplitude() always return 0.

```
MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RecorderTask(recorder), 0, 500);
    recorder.setOutputFile(fileName);
    try {
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    } catch(IllegalStateException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

private class RecorderTask extends TimerTask {
    private MediaRecorder recorder;

    public RecorderTask(MediaRecorder recorder) {
        this.recorder = recorder;
    }

    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int amplitude = recorder.getMaxAmplitude();
                Log.d("amplitude",""+amplitude);
            }
        });
    }
}
```